# Database Connections - Security - GitHub + Phonegap Build

Tags: database, cordova, github, build, connection

I have several websites with databases and want to use them to support my Phonegap apps.

I'm using Phonegap Build and opened my first Git repository (Public) to draw projects from.   (I am allowed one 'Private' and several 'Public' reps.)

Am I correct in assuming that I should never include actual working hostname/password/dbnames in my MySQL connection scripts in my PUBLIC repositories?   (Because this is obviously a major security gaffe)  Am I also  correct in assuming that I need to explicitly use PRIVATE reps if I want to use an actual working DB connection in my apps?

(Thanks for any help, I'm new to Phonegap, Phonegap Build, and GitHub..)

Comment: Does your app connect to db via web server?

Comment: hi neil, yes that is my intention.  ill be using standard AJAX calls but am confused as to security and how to go about this with phonegap/github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store db passwords in files. Store them in O/S user environment variables.

Run your web server as user foo. Store O/S env var for user foo.

- O/S user env vars can only be read by that user or root
- Can't screw up file permissions

Comment: ok, am i supposed to use javascript to write a cookie or something to the local device?   at some point the password/conn info will be in a js file or something in that repository that build uses to create the app.  it seems obvious to me that this cannot be a PUBLIC repository, i just need to confirm this assumption.

Comment: @Edward you said your app connects via a web server yes? The client should not know the db password, only the web server should.

Comment: oh, i think i get it.   so my (Public) repository will contain files with AJAX calls to "getdata.php" on my web server.  however, the only actual dbname/password script is on my webserver ("connecttodb.php") and is called in "getdata.php".     in this sense, it doesnt matter if i use PUBLIC or PRIVATE reps because i never include the connection script or information in the repository, is that correct?

Comment: @Edward I think we're talking the same language now :) You can keep your ajax client in a public repo. You can even keep your web server code in a public repo. Just avoid putting db password in public repo.

Comment: thanks boss, crystal clear now.  for me, first time phonegap and github user, i lost sight of the basic server/client dynamic.

Comment: for any other new phonegap+build+github users with multiple sites/apps i want to add that your URLs will have to be specific to your website.  i.e.: "http://www.mysite1.com/getdata.php"